# How to persist session data, available to a business layer

Tags: c#, asp.net, persistence

I am building an ASP.Net MVC 4 application. Users have to log in and accounts are checked against a database. In this database, users are associated to one or more departments. The requirements state that a user has can only use the application for one department at a time.

This means that after a successful login, I check to see how many departments the user is linked to. If this is just one, it will be the active department. If it is more than one, I will ask the user to choose one of them and this choice will be the active department. This value must persist throughout the session.

There are many use cases in the application that must only give access to data that belongs to the active department. These restrictions are applied in a business layer, that is, a C# class library that does not know about the ASP.Net context.

How could I best persist the user's selection for the active department? I do not like the idea of storing this in de database very much, as it is not persistent beyond the session. On the other hand, in my business layer, I cannot find any out-of-the-box persistence provisioning. My ASP.net application provides a Session, but these are invisible for the business layer.

Should I store this value in the Session and use the AuthenticateRequest Event or something like that, to pass the active department to the business layer?

Any better alternatives?

Comment: These are invisible for the business layer? What do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storing the active department can be done in a Session variable:

`Session["ActiveDepartment"] = 1`

You don't need session management in your business logic.  Write a wrapper around your business logic assembly that requires an ActiveDepartmentID provided to all calls in order to be valid.  The wrapper always returns data filtered by ActiveDepartmentID.

Since this is an MVC application, you could also enforce this at the Controller level by requiring an ActiveDepartmentID in all Controller actions.

Comment: I choose this as the answer, because it provides a better alternative. I do not like the reference to System.Web in my BL project.

Answer (score 3):

These are invisible for the business layer? What do you mean?

You can actually access your session from class library. What you have to do is reference `System.Web` then:

1) import the namespace in your code

2) `var sessionValue = HttpContext.Current.Session["ActiveDepartment"];`

Alternatively, you can pass the `ActiveDepartment` to your business layer every time you need it instead of getting it from the session so you are not tied to a web application

Comment: I meant by invisible that the BL class library does not have a reference to the Web application project. However, I now see that it is not needed.

Comment: Actually, it surprises me that this works at all. I tested this by storing a value in a Controller's Session property and retrieving it in a subsequent request from the HttpContext.Current.Session in the business layer. I assume this will only work if the BL assembly is loaded in a web application context.